# Проблема с переключателем валют на сайте js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытаюсь сделать на сайте (wordpress) переключатель валют. Основная валюта USD.
Имеется переключатель:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.converter li').click(function() {
    $('.converter li').removeClass('active');
    var c = $(this).addClass('active').text().toLowerCase();
    // createCookie("carrency",c,30);
    $('[data-byn]').each(function() {
      $(this).html($(this).data(c))
    });
    return !1;
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li title="Белорусский рубль">BYN</li>
  <li title="Российский рубль">RUB</li>
  <li class="active" title="Доллар США">USD</li>
</ul>


<!-------- Данные для вывода: -------->
<span data-rub="1740 Е" data-byn="60 р." data-usd="$ 30">$ 30</span>
```

В итоге получаю не кликабельный переключатель и "съехавший" header.
Очень прошу помочь гуру. адрес пациента https://autorenta.by/test/

Comment: класс указать то забыли `<ul class="converter"> `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант (решения):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.converter li').click(function() {
    $('.converter li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active'); // Added
    var c = $(this).addClass('active').text().toLowerCase();

    // createCookie("carrency",c,30);
   
    $('[data-byn]').each(function() {
      $(this).html($(this).data(c))
    })
    
    // return !1; // commented
  });
})
```

```css
.active{
  background: yellow;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!-------- Added jQuery -------->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-------- Added class converter -------->
<ul class="converter">
  <li title="Белорусский рубль">BYN</li>
  <li title="Российский рубль">RUB</li>
  <li class="active" title="Доллар США">USD</li>
</ul>


<!-------- Данные для вывода: -------->
<span data-rub="1740 Е" data-byn="60 р." data-usd="$ 30">$ 30</span>
```

---

**UPD**: Пояснения в коде.

Comment: вариант чего? поясните, что вы изменили, и что было не правильно в коде в вопросе

Comment: Спасибо за Вашу помощь. Вставить в скрипт Ваш код http://autorenta.by/currency.js. также добавил классы .active и .converter и все равно переключатель не кликабельный. проблема в этом, как бы щелчка/переключения не происходит.

Comment: @KostaB. прошу помощи, все сделал, не переключается сумма...

Comment: @BLack_CaT у вас есть `jQuery` в проекте?

Comment: @KostaB. простите я не программер, не смогу ответить вам, я использую шаблон avada на wordpress. подключен <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @BLack_CaT добавьте `js` код из примера на свою страницу, сразу все заработает. После кода `jQuery`.